# Netsuite error :You are not requesting the correct data center for your company"

Tags: php, netsuite

I using Netsuite PHPToolkit version 2014_1.

```
$nsendpoint = "2014_1";
$nshost = "https://webservices.netsuite.com";
```

Today I received this error when login via webservice

> You are not requesting the correct data center for your company ! Please correct the host in the URL.

This is my response

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <soapenv:Fault>
            <faultcode>
                soapenv:Server.userException
            </faultcode>
            <faultstring>
                You are not requesting the correct data center for your company ! Please correct the host in the URL.
            </faultstring>
            <detail>
                <platformFaults:unexpectedErrorFault xmlns:platformFaults="urn:faults_2014_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">
                    <platformFaults:code>
                        USER_ERROR
                    </platformFaults:code>
                    <platformFaults:message>
                        You are not requesting the correct data center for your company ! Please correct the host in the URL.
                    </platformFaults:message>
                </platformFaults:unexpectedErrorFault>
                <ns1:hostname xmlns:ns1="http://xml.apache.org/axis/">
                    partners-java10010.bos.netledger.com
                </ns1:hostname>
            </detail>
        </soapenv:Fault>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

It was working well before.

Answer (score 4):

Today the NetSuite Data Center URL is different for each customer.

After configuring NSconfig.php, run the following script to identify the endpoint URL. The example comes from the samples folder of PHPToolkit_2018_2,

```
require_once 'PHPToolkit/NetSuiteService.php';

$service = new NetSuiteService();
$service->useRequestLevelCredentials(false);

$params = new GetDataCenterUrlsRequest();
$params->account = NS_ACCOUNT;
$response = $service->getDataCenterUrls($params);
$webservicesDomain = $response->getDataCenterUrlsResult->dataCenterUrls->webservicesDomain;
print "url: $webservicesDomain";
```

Once you have the URL you can then enter that in your configuration.

Answer (score 2):

I've come across that error but not in that context.
I have found it whilst working on accounts that have the system.netsuite.com data center specified and sometimes have to switch to system.**na1**.netsuite.com 
I would give **na1** a try.

I believe it's related to the 2 data centers across the States, East / West Coast and the way requests are routed.

Answer (score 2):

The answer from @Charlie Dalsass to use `getDataCenterUrls` is 100% correct if your SuiteTalk client will be accessing multiple NetSuite accounts.

However, if your client will only use one account, you can probably get away with hardcoding the URL

```
https://1234567.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com
```

where `1234567` is your account ID. So, an example WSDL URL you'd pass to your SOAP client would be

```
https://1234567.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/wsdl/v2018_1_0/netsuite.wsdl
```

Comment: Can you please help me to solve issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57429656/netsuite-error-you-must-use-account-specific-domains-with-the-2019-1-soap-web-s

Answer (score 0):

Endpoint needs to be "https://webservices.na1.netsuite.com" not "https://webservices.netsuite.com", kind of annoying.

Comment: I tried both url, i get 404 not found. Do we know why?

Answer (score 0):

I got this error , but for me the mistake was with my account_id I was using, it's case sensitive